# Why I cannot install the "React-Navigation" on my React-Native Project

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

I copied the Installation code from [React-Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/#installation) site, then I copied the installation code and paste it within the project terminal and It couldn't support it, so please this error soon as possible.

Installation

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

Thin I installed

```
npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

and I'll attach the screenshot below so please check it and give the solution!

I tried to Install the "react-navigation" but I can't do this in my project so please guide me, Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using expo please install using below command

```
npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

Comment: Ah ok ok, I found it Thanks, bro!

Comment: If this solves the issue. Please mark it as solved. thanks